# Can't log in to site under Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a strange issue where I am unable to log into a site under test with the Selenium WebDriver, but am not having any issues logging in when running the project under test in Visual Studio, or in our QA environment.

I have broken the test down to the most simplistic example, where it allows me to manually enter the username, password, and click the login button while it waits for verification that it has moved on to the next screen (waits for an element on that page).

All that happens when running under Selenium is a page refresh.

The test:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this._baseURL + "Account/Index");
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Id("element-on-next-page")));
```

The login button calls the jQuery `$.ajax` method to POST data to a service, and is correctly going into the `success()` method.  The service returns a redirect URL.

This, in turn, attempts to redirect, which works when working with the site manually, but simply re-loads the login page when under a Selenium test:

```
window.location.replace(location.origin + result.RedirectTo);
```

I have verified that the result.RedirectTo is valid when the test is running (it is the page it should be redirecting to for successful login).

> Tested with Chrome 71.0.3578.98, Firefox 64.0.2 and IE 11.472.17134.0.  It works fine manually in all three.

I am unsure why this behavior is acting differently under automation.

**UPDATE**: The page it is attempting to redirect to has an `[Authorize()]` attribute on the controller.  Removing this attribute allows the test to pass.  The attribute only causes Selenium tests to fail, not manual testing.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue.  It does not seem like an ideal scenario to remove the [Authorize()] attribute from the controller in order to get our Selenium tests to pass.  Would this be considered a bug in Selenium or the Chrome Driver?

Answer (score 0):

have to try to perform login steps manually on the chrome browser launched by Selenium?

I am not sure but sometimes google redirects to authorization page or verify your identity page just to ensure you are not using automation scripts for creating multiple emails signup or **scraping** any website data.

Just try to run the same scenario manually on the browser launched by selenium.

Comment: Yes, that's what the minimum code example is doing.  It launches the login page and waits for the second page while I manually type in username/password and click the enter button.  It does the same thing as under test, it just refreshes the page.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, you should probably delete it or it will get removed by moderators.